# ReactJs cannot acess nested route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested-routes

I have an issue using nested routes with react-router.

Here is my code (two simple react components, routes file to access comp1/comp2) :

House.js

```
export default connect(st => st)(class House extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div>       
    {this.props.children}
   </div>
  );
 }
})
```

Window.js

```
export default connect(st => st)(class Window extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        hey hey
      </div>
    );
  }
})
```

routes.js

```
export const routes = (
  <Router history={ history }>
    <Route path="/house" component={House}>
      <Route path="/house/window" component={Window} />
   </Route>
 </Router>
);
```

When I redirect to "/house/window" programmatically, I can access the route and the page shows "hey hey".
If I want to access the url directly :
localhost:8080/house/window

It shows a blank page and a console error :

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/house/window
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified

And then :
GET http:// localhost:8080 /house/js/bundle.js   (404)

Also, http:// localhost:8080 /house/ (with trailing slash) shows the same error.

I really don't understand this weird redirection   http:// localhost:8080  /house/js/bundle.js

I'm probably doing something wrong, but after crawling stackoverflow, I still can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue : my bundle.js script included in index.html was included with a relative path 'js/bundle.js' so I changed it for '/js/bundle.js'.

Sadly, it didn't make any problem until I wanted to nest some routes.

Answer (score 0):

Nested routes cannot have parent path included in `path` attribute:

```
export const routes = (
  <Router history={ history }>
    <Route path="/house/" component={House}>
      <Route path="window" component={Window} />
   </Route>
 </Router>
);
```

Comment: I have the same issue nesting this way and trying to access /house/window, but I can access /window .

Comment: Have you enabled hotmodule reloading or restarted server? BTW I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, the updated answer doesn't work either for me. I'm only using webpack --watch and npm start to work locally

Comment: And still have the same issue after restarting the server

Comment: I found the issue : my bundle.js script included in index.html was included with a relative path 'js/bundle.js'  so I changed it for '/js/bundle.js'.